# How to declare range object properly and index range contents properly

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very new to VBA, and almost everything in my function so far works fine; it takes chosen cell ranges "counts","data","idealxS" as inputs, along with constants "alpha" and "C", and ideally will take the "idealxS" and transform them "idealxs"--->"newidealxs" using the formula in the for loop, then it'll take the transformed "newidealxS" and "counts" and sum the squares of the differences.

```
Public Function TERMCALCULATION(data As Range, counts As Range, idealxS As Range, alpha, C)
avg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(data)
stdv = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(data)
siz = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(counts)
constant1 = (1 / (stdv * ((2 * 3.14159265358979) ^ (1 / 2))))
Dim newidealxS As Range
For i = 1 To siz
Debug.Print i
term1 = ((2.71828182845905) ^ (-(((idealxS(i, 1) - avg) / stdv) ^ 2) / 2))
term2 = (1 + Application.WorksheetFunction.Erf(0, (alpha * (((idealxS(i, 1) - avg)) / (stdv * (2 ^ (1 / 2)))))))
newidealxS(i, 1).Value = C * constant1 * term1 * term2
Next i
Debug.Print idealxS(68)
TERMCALCULATION = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumXMY2(counts, newidealxS)
End Function
```

What really happens is that there's an error when I try to define the "newidealxS", and I don't know how to properly declare the range object or something, or it could be that I'm not indexing the created range correctly. Every other part of the code works. I don't need the cell values to be stored somwhere, I need them to be dummy garbage variables that get thrown out after the iteration of the function you know, like the avg and stdv, but it seems that when I try to have something like that that's a range it doesn't work, so I'm not sure if ranges even work like that or if I should be defining a new array (but then I couldn't use the SumXMY2 command). I have absolutely no prior knowledge with VBA, so please be as explicit as possible!

Comment: Is the error on Dim newidealxS As Range or newidealxS(i, 1).Value = C * constant1 * term1 * term2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using an array instead of a range for `newidealxS`:

```
Public Function TERMCALCULATION(data As Range, counts As Range, _
                                idealxS As Range, alpha, C)

    Dim avg, stdv, siz As Long, constant1, wsf, i As Long
    Dim term1, term2
    Dim newidealxS() '<< array, not range

    Set wsf = Application.WorksheetFunction

    avg = wsf.Average(data)
    stdv = wsf.stdev(data)
    siz = wsf.Count(counts)
    constant1 = (1 / (stdv * ((2 * 3.14159265358979) ^ (1 / 2))))

    ReDim newidealxS(1 To siz, 1 To 1)

    For i = 1 To siz
        Debug.Print i
        term1 = ((2.71828182845905) ^ (-(((idealxS(i, 1) - avg) / stdv) ^ 2) / 2))
        term2 = (1 + wsf.Erf(0, (alpha * (((idealxS(i, 1) - avg)) / (stdv * (2 ^ (1 / 2)))))))
        newidealxS(i, 1) = C * constant1 * term1 * term2 '<<EDIT: removed .Value
    Next i

    Debug.Print idealxS(68)

    TERMCALCULATION = wsf.SumXMY2(counts, newidealxS)

End Function
```

Comment: I get an invalid qualifier error at the newidealxS(i, 1).Value when I change to an array.

Comment: When I straight up copied your code it went fine all the way until that first assignment of newidealxS(1,1) then wouldn't perform that line and cut out.

Comment: Any chance you could post some sample data? (smallish set is fine)

Comment: data =[9,96,90,96,93,3],counts=[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0], idealxS=[0,1,2...97,98,99] (for the sake of compressing my comment), and alpha and C could be anything but values of 4.8 and 13.5 should let the final output be like 8. something.

Comment: the first "9" should be "90", but it doesn't super matter

Comment: My bad - forgot to remove the `.Value` after switching to an array vs Range...   See my edit above.   I get 8.4 from those inputs.

Comment: It works perfectly!!! Thank you so much, before this morning I didn't know VBA even existed or what it was, so my day has been an attempt to not drown after jumping in, and you literally just saved me!!!! :D I didn't really get the concept of Ranges and what they needed and stuff